# Titles in Google Sheets Charts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

When I first create a chart in Google Sheets, the Title is in a movable box that I can select and drag around inside the chart box.

If I then change that title programmatically, e.g.

```
        chart = chart.modify()
        .setOption('title',ChartTitleNameReplacement)
        .build();
        selectedSheet.updateChart(chart);
```

the Title jumps up to the top of the chart box and cannot be dragged anywhere.

What option setting do I need in the Google Apps Script code to keep that box movable? Alternatively, is there any way of specifying a position in the chart box for the Title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue with your situation. I think that this might be a bug. In this case, I achieved to modify the title without locking the title position using Sheets API. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you run the script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
const updatedTitle = "### updated title ###";

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const ssId = ss.getId();
const chart = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId).sheets[0].charts[0];
delete chart.position;
chart.spec.title = updatedTitle;
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: [{updateChartSpec: chart}]}, ssId);
```

- In this case, the title of the 1st chart in the 1st sheet in the active Google Spreadsheet is modified.

#### Note:

- When only the title is modified, an error like the internal error occurs. At `UpdateChartSpecRequest`, there is no `fields`. I think that this might be the reason of the issue. So I added the existing properties to the request body by modifying the title. Please be careful this.
- In the current stage, when the title is updated, it seems the title position is reset.
- This is a simple sample script for modifying the chart title without locking the title position. So please modify this for your actual situation.
- I couldn't find this issue at [the issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). So how about reporting it?

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateChartSpecRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatechartspecrequest)

Comment: I have reported it. Thanks for the encouragement so to do.

Comment: @bugmagnet Thank you for replying. In my environment, I could confirm that above workaround works. Can I ask you whether it worked in your environment?

Comment: yes, it has worked in my environment. Therefore I have ticked your solution as THE answer.

Comment: @bugmagnet Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad the script worked in your environment. Thank you, too.