# Why are Slice Labels disabled when changing Title/SubTitle in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Earlier it was [pointed out to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62059874/titles-in-google-sheets-charts) how to change a title or subtitle in a 3D pie chart with a pieHole and have the title remain as a floating text box.

One of the unpleasant side effects of this was the removal of the slice labels, that is from this
[image: Before titles change]

to this

[image: After titles change]

The code I'm using for this is

```
function UpdateSubTitleAdvanced(sheetName, chartId, newTitle) {
  const active = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = active.getId();
  const sheets = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId).sheets;
  for (let s in sheets) {
    let sheet = sheets[s];
    if (sheet.properties.title === sheetName) {
      for (let c in sheet.charts) {
        let chart = sheet.charts[c];
        if (chart.chartId === chartId) {
          Logger.log("Sheet %s, Chart %s, Title '%s', SubTitle '%s'", sheet.properties.title, String(chart.chartId), chart.spec.title, chart.spec.subtitle); 
          delete chart.position;
          chart.spec.subtitle = newTitle;
          Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests:[{updateChartSpec: chart}]}, ssId);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function _UpdateSubTitle() {
  UpdateSubTitleAdvanced("Group0",713335354,"### new sub title");
}
```

There doesn't appear to be anything in the code that explicitly knobbles the slice labels. Nor is there much of anything in the documentation regarding how to put them back.

I have had some success in capturing the HAR of the browser session and extracting the JSON structure describing the graphic.

```
{
    "chartType": "PieChart",
    "options": {
        "pieSliceTextStyle": {
            "fontSize": 10
        },
        "legend": "none",
        "annotations": {
            "total": {
                "textStyle": {}
            },
            "domain": {
                "textStyle": {}
            }
        },
        "is3D": true,
        "title": "### new sub title",
        "titleTextStyle": {
            "fontName": "serif",
            "alignment": "center"
        },
        "pieSliceText": "label",
        "fontName": "serif",
        "legendTextStyle": {},
        "pieHole": 0.5,
        "bubble": {
            "textStyle": {}
        },
        "useFirstColumnAsDomain": true,
        "subtitleTextStyle": {
            "fontName": "sans-serif",
            "color": "#000000",
            "fontSize": 16,
            "bold": true,
            "alignment": "center"
        },
        "subtitle": "influencer marketing",
        "width": 600,
        "textStyle": {
            "fontName": "serif"
        },
        "chartArea": {
            "top": "1.8585131894484377%",
            "left": "1.4962121212121169%",
            "width": "98.50378787878789%",
            "height": "96.88249400479617%"
        },
        "height": 371
    },
    "initialView": {}
}
```

I haven't tried changing any of them programmatically as yet.

What can be done here? I want to achieve the following:

- Keep the title or subtitle box movable.
- Keep the slices named.
- Find a way to have the title or subtitle centred in the image.
- Keep the image maximised within the chart frame (the images would seem to indicate that the above code affects the image size.)

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for your earlier response. It appeared to work but had some unpleasant side-effects which I have listed above.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. It seems that this issue is due to the current specification at Google side. About the current issue and future, I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

How about this answer?

#### Current issue:

The reason of this issue is that in the current stage, the property of "Slice label" is not included in the object retrieved by the method of "spreadsheets.get" in Sheets API. This can be seen at the following object of the chart. This object is retrieved by the method of "spreadsheets.get" in Sheets API.

```
{
  "chartId": ###,
  "spec": {
    "title": "sample title",
    "pieChart": {
      "legendPosition": "LABELED_LEGEND",
      "domain": {
        "sourceRange": {
          "sources": [
            {
              "sheetId": ###,
              "startRowIndex": 0,
              "endRowIndex": 5,
              "startColumnIndex": 0,
              "endColumnIndex": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "series": {
        "sourceRange": {
          "sources": [
            {
              "sheetId": ###,
              "startRowIndex": 0,
              "endRowIndex": 5,
              "startColumnIndex": 1,
              "endColumnIndex": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "threeDimensional": true,
      "pieHole": 0.5
    },
    "hiddenDimensionStrategy": "SKIP_HIDDEN_ROWS_AND_COLUMNS",
    "titleTextFormat": {
      "fontFamily": "Roboto"
    },
    "fontName": "Roboto"
  },
  "position": {
    "overlayPosition": {
      "anchorCell": {
        "sheetId": ###,
        "rowIndex": 1,
        "columnIndex": 1
      },
      "offsetXPixels": 69,
      "offsetYPixels": 17,
      "widthPixels": 600,
      "heightPixels": 371
    }
  }
}
```

From above chart object, it is found that the property of "Slice label" is not included. By this, when the chart is updated using the retrieved values from the chart, "Slice label" is removed. And also, "UpdateChartSpecRequest" has no property for setting "Slice label" yet. By this, the workaround cannot be used yet.

And also, about the last your 4 requests, in the current stage, these are not included in the chart object of both the method of "spreadsheets.get" and "UpdateChartSpecRequest".

Unfortunately, these are the current specification at Google side. The Sheets API is growing now. So I believe that these properties will be added in the future update.

#### Future:

I thought that the reason of such issue is due to that "updateChartSpec" was not updated with `fields` property. When `fields` property could be used, for example, only the chart title can be updated. By this, even when the property of "Slice label" is not included in the current "UpdateChartSpecRequest", only the chart title can be updated. In this case, your current issue will not occur. So I have already reported this as the future request at the issue tracker at May 28, 2020. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157597999) And that has already been accepted. So I think that Google might modify this in the near future.

#### Reference:

- [UpdateChartSpecRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatechartspecrequest)