# How to update Chart Title via Google Sheet API (python)

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a google chart whose ID I have already extracted via .get method.

I now need to change the title of the chart (and nothing else).  The charts come from external template, so I do not know anything about them, other than the name.

I tried the following request:

```
body = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateChartSpec": {
        "chartId": 1944564251,
        "spec": {
          "title": "NEW NAME OF CHART"}
      }}]
    }
        
r = sheet.batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=DESTINATION_SPREADSHEET_ID, body=body).execute()
```

but I am getting this error:
`"Invalid requests[0].updateChartSpec: One of basicChart, pieChart, bubbleChart, candelstickChart, histogramChart, or orgChart must be set on chartSpec."`

I don't want to change anything in the chart other than the title.  How can I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to modify the title of the chart on Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- In the current stage, it seems that `UpdateChartSpecRequest` of Sheets API cannot still update the chart title using only the property of title. I thought that the reason of your issue is due to this. This has already been reported to the issue tracker as a Feature Request. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157597999)
- I think that if `fields` is added to this request, your script might work. But, in the current stage, it is required to use the workaround.
- The workaround is as follows.

  1. Retrieve the chart object using the chart ID and spreadsheets.get method in Sheets API.
  2. Modify the chart object.
  3. Using `UpdateChartSpecRequest`, the modified chart object is used. By this, the chart is updated.
- I have already answered this workaround at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62060874). But, this is for Google Apps Script. When I searched this workaround using googleapis for Python, I couldn't find it. So I answerd this using googleapis for Python.

When above workaround is reflected to the script of Python, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
DESTINATION_SPREADSHEET_ID = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
chartId = 1944564251 # Please set the chart ID.
newTitle = "NEW NAME OF CHART"

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
res = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=DESTINATION_SPREADSHEET_ID, fields='sheets(charts)').execute()
chart = None
for s in res.get('sheets'):
    charts = s.get('charts')
    if charts:
        for c in charts:
            if c.get('chartId') == chartId:
                chart = c
if chart:
    chart.pop('position')
    chart['spec']['title'] = newTitle
    body = {"requests": [{"updateChartSpec": chart}]}
    r = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=DESTINATION_SPREADSHEET_ID, body=body).execute()
    print(r)
else:
    print("Chart cannot be found.")
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateChartSpecRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatechartspecrequest)
- Issue tracker.

  - [Add fields property to UpdateChartSpecRequest of batchUpdate method in Sheets API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157597999)

## Added:

From your following replying,

> Thank you for your response. I tried the code above and getting this error: `Invalid requests[0].updateChartSpec: chartSpec.basicChart.lineSmoothing not supported when chartSpec.basicChart.chartType is COMBO`

I could replicate your error. I confirmed that in the current stage, it seems that `"lineSmoothing": true` cannot be used with `COMBO` chart using `UpdateChartSpecRequest`. So in the current stage, when Sheets API is used, it is required to remove the property of `"lineSmoothing": true` as follows. In this case, please modify above sample script as follows.

#### From:

```
if chart:
    chart.pop('position')
```

#### To:

```
if chart:
    chart.pop('position')
    if chart['spec'].get('basicChart') and chart['spec']['basicChart']['chartType'] == 'COMBO' and chart['spec']['basicChart'].get('lineSmoothing') and chart['spec']['basicChart']['lineSmoothing'] == True:
        chart['spec']['basicChart'].pop('lineSmoothing')
```

By above modification, the error can be removed. But in this case, unfortunately, the chart is changed. Because `"lineSmoothing": true` is not used. So, in this case, how about reporting this issue as the issue tracker as the future request? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

So, as a workaround, how about the following method? In this workaround, Web Apps created by Google Apps Script is used as the wrapper API. When Google Apps Script is used, the chart title can be directly modified.

### Usage:

#### 1. Create new project of Google Apps Script.

Sample script of Web Apps is a Google Apps Script. So please create a project of Google Apps Script.

If you want to directly create it, please access to https://script.new/. In this case, if you are not logged in Google, the log in screen is opened. So please log in to Google. By this, the script editor of Google Apps Script is opened.

#### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the created Google Apps Script project and save it.

```
function doGet(e) {
  const {spreadsheetId, chartId, newTitle} = e.parameter;
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheets();
  let done = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    const charts = sheets[i].getCharts();
    for (let j = 0; j < charts.length; j++) {
      if (charts[j].getChartId() == chartId) {
        const chart = charts[j].modify().setOption("title", newTitle).build();
        sheets[i].updateChart(chart);
        done = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (done) break;
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.");
}
```

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

The detail information can be seen at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.

   - This is the important of this workaround.
5. Please select **"Anyone"** for **"Who has access"**.

   - In this case, the user is not required to use the access token. So please use this as a test case.
   - Of course, you can also access to your Web Apps using the access token. Please check [this report](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#accesstokenforaccessingtowebapps).
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. Copy the URL of Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
   - You can see the detail of this at the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### 4. Testing.

When above Web Apps is tested, the sample python script is as follows. Please set your URL of Web Apps.

```
import requests
url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
url += "?spreadsheetId=###&chartId=###&newTitle=###"
res = requests.get(url)
print(res.text)
```

- **When an error occurs, please confirm the settings of Web Apps again.**

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried the code above and getting this error: `Invalid requests[0].updateChartSpec: chartSpec.basicChart.lineSmoothing not supported when chartSpec.basicChart.chartType is COMBO`

Comment: @yulGM Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I could replicate your issue. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: thank you.  unfortunately i'm not able to use the web apps for this task (outside scope).  I tried running it after popping lineSmoothing.  it doesn't seem to change graph appearance, but it removed legend titles at the top of the chart...  I'm going to probe in that direction now that I know what was causing errors.  I will mark your answer as accepted as it helped me to get the code running.

Comment: @yulGM Thank you for replying and more information.